# How to avoid a trail of delegate calls

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

I have a `UIViewController` which has a `UICollectionView`, inside that I have a `ListSectionController` class that controls a `UICollectionViewCell`, and inside that cell I have a `UIView` subclass.

When a button is pressed I need to call a method from the `UIViewController`. Currently I have a trail of delegate methods as it works it's way back to the view controller like this:

```
class MyView {
    // delegate is the cell that the view is contained in

    @IBAction func buttonPress() {
        delegate?.myDelegateMethod()
    }
}

extension MyCell : MyViewDelegate {
    // The delegate is the section controller

    func myDelegateMethod() {
        delegate?.myDelegateMethod()
    }
}

... etc
```

This seem like a lot of code duplication and a bit of a waste of space. How can I improve that?

Comment: Delegate of `MyView` doesn't have to be the cell, it can be view controller. Just pass it down all the way to the view upon cell creation

Comment: This is how it supposed to work to properly separate implementations. However, I would use closures (callback blocks) for almost everything nowadays.

Comment: you can use Notification center as alternative of delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When a button is pressed I need to call a method from the UIViewController

One way: give the button a *nil-targeted action* and implement the action method in the UIViewController. The message will arrive automatically.

For example, we give the button a nil-targeted action:

```
    class Dummy {
        @objc func buttonPressed(_:Any) {}
    }
    button.addTarget(nil,
        action: #selector(Dummy.buttonPressed),
        for: .touchUpInside)
```

And in the view controller we have:

```
    @objc func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
```

This will work, because the view controller is located *up the responder chain* from the button. This is exactly what nil-targeted actions are for.

---

Another way is to use NotificationCenter and Notification. I think that’s perfectly appropriate in this situation as well.

Comment: Wow, never heard of nil-targeted actions before!

Answer (score 0):

You can reach straight up the responder chain to any parent view or view controller in a generic, type safe way:

```
extension UIResponder {
    func firstParent<T: UIResponder>(ofType type: T.Type ) -> T? {
        return next as? T ?? next.flatMap { $0.firstParent(ofType: type) }
    }
}
```

```
guard let ListSectionController = firstParent(ofType: ListSectionController) else {
 return // we aren't in a ListSectionController
}
//Call ListSectionController methods here
```

Comment: And this is definitely not a good solution because it breaks encapsulation.

Comment: @Sulthan we have to agree to disagree about that one.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this condition so many time hence I would like to state obvious first:

"If your cell (and views inside it) are responsible of performing one and only one action (may be that is form button inside it)", you can use `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`". By designing your view with `UIImageView`. This approach have some UX issue such as, highlight and all but those can be handled with delegate as well.

If that is not the case and you cell is performing more than one action Mat's answer give best approaches.